# MarkerClick event in Kendo UI map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, kendo-ui

In my `.cshtml` file I have a header `<h2 id="venueName"></h2>` and a Kendo Map with `MarkerClick` event defined like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Map()
    .Name("map")
    .Center(-25.8671083, 133.6768307)
    .Zoom(4)
    .Layers(layers =>
        {
            ...
        })
    .Events(events => events
        .MarkerClick("onMarkerClicked")
    )
)
```

Here is the script for the event

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onMarkerClicked(e) {
        $("#venueName").text("Venue 1");
    }
</script>
```

The question is: When I click the marker, the header doesn't change to `Venue 1`. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: For anyone finding this now (2017), `.MarkerClick("functionName")` works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its something strange that kendo map don't provide "MarkerClick" event when the map is defined in html.
Also trying to bind "MarkerClick" event after initialization of the map don't work. I used the following code:

```
  var map = $("#map").data("kendoMap");
    map.bind("markerClick", function (e) {
        alert("assx");
    });
```

But the same code works for other enevts like "zoomStart" etc.

Surprisingly if the map is defined in javascript it is possible to raise the "MarkerClick" event. i.e.

```
  $("#map").kendoMap({
            center: [30.268107, -97.744821],
            zoom: 3,
            markerClick: clicked,
            //other declarations..
    });

 function clicked(e){
    alert("assx");
    //$("#venueName").text("Venue 1") also works.
  }
```

This is what I could able to find.
Hope it helps!

Comment: yeah that's weird... I saw some example on kendo website and they all defined the map in javascript with the markerclick event. I was thinking about it too but I want to define the map in html since all other kendo elements in my project are in html.
guess I have to switch the map to javascript then.
thank you!